# "Weit weg von zu Hause"

Tags: spelling, grammar-identification

Laut DUDEN heißt es **weit weg von zu Hause**. Könntet Ihr mir bitte erklären, warum "zu Hause" in diesem Fall getrennt geschrieben wird? Ich dachte, es wäre ein Substantiv hier...

Answer (score 4):

Das Substantiv [*Zuhause*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zuhause) beschreibt die Räumlichkeiten, in denen jemand wohnt.

> - Er hatte bereits mit 16 ein eigenes *Zuhause*.
> - Bist du mit deinem neuen *Zuhause* zufrieden?

Es ist durch [Nominalisierung](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung) aus dem Adverb [*zu Hause*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/zu_Hause) hervorgegangen. Das Adverb wird häufig zur adverbialen Bestimmung des Ortes verwendet und ist ein Synonym von [*daheim*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/daheim). Seit der [Rechtschreibreform 2004/2006](https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/zuhause.shtml) kann das Adverb auch zusammengeschrieben werden, dann aber natürlich klein, d. h. [*zuhause*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/zuhause).

> - Sind Sie schon *zu Hause*/ *zuhause*/ *daheim*?
> - Sie war **weit weg von *zu Hause***/ *zuhause* / *daheim*.

Comment: Adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit?

Comment: @Janka, oh je :-) Ich hab's korrigiert.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort! =)

Answer (score 2):

Zunächst gibt es laut Duden zwei Möglichkeiten, *zu Hause* zu schreiben.

> Von Duden empfohlene Schreibung: zu Hause
>   Alternative Schreibung: zuhause

[Duden.de/zu_Hause](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zu_Hause)

Es handelt sich hier um eine adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes. Vergleiche auch

> Weit weg von **hier**
>   Weit weg von **dort**
>   Weit weg von **zuhause** / **zu Hause**

edit:

Es wird groß und zusammengeschrieben, wenn Du es z.B. mit einem Possesivpronomen versiehst:

> Weit weg von meinem Zuhause.

Comment: Vielen Dank! jetzt ist es mir klar =)